# Backbone Coffeescript Save Success Function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to implement a success function inside a save call in my backbone basic survey app I'm creating to help me learn backbone. After the user finishes the last question a new completion is created. My server only allows a user to take the survey once, so when the user tries to submit the same completion a 500 Internal Error is returned noting the completion was not created.

The problem is that the success function seems to be getting called both when the response is 201 and when it's 500. Any idea how I need to change my save function such that the success is only called when the response is 201 and not 500?

```
updateQuestion: ->
    if @questionNumber < @questionLimit
      @questionNumber += 1
      $("#container").html(@render().el)
      choice = new SurveyMe.Models.Choice
      choice.save(
        choice:
          appuser_id: Cookie.get('survey_user_id')
          question_id: @model.get('questions')[@questionNumber]["id"]
          answer_id: "4"
      )
      @renderQuestion()
    else
      completion = new SurveyMe.Models.Completion
      completion.save(
        {
        completion:
          survey_id: @model.get('id')
          appuser_id: Cookie.get('survey_user_id')
        },
        success: 
          @model.save(
            number_taken: @model.get('number_taken') + 1
          )
      )
      Backbone.history.navigate("surveys",trigger: true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the success function immediately rather than referencing it for execution later. Try something like this:

```
success: (res) =>
  @model.save(number_taken: @model.get('number_taken') + 1)
```

Comment: The problem with that is the success function doesn't seem to be called at all when adding a -> or =>. I wonder if part of my problem is trying to learn backbone and coffeescript at the same time :).

Comment: Are you returning JSON from the server? It may be that it is not seeing it as successful even when 201. But yes, it might be good to see if you can get it working in JS first and go from there. Either way, you have specify your function like I proposed for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
@statusCode = PostData:->
    @save({completion:{"yourValues"},
        success:=>
            @SaveOtherInformation()  
         )

@saveOtherInformation:->
    //Perform the other 'Save' if the status code is according to your server response.

    @save() if @statusCode is "201"
```

I suggest you try to separate the view from model avoiding dom manipulation inside your model, and model manipulation inside your view. It will make your life quite easy.